# Pinterest - Got a error when create pin

Tags: android

After authenticate, I create a board and the board name is "App" then create a pin but is how error link

```
{"message": "Board not found.", "type": "api", "param": "board"}
```

Create pin code :

```
 String pinImageUrl = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/697057/pexels-photo-697057.jpeg";
    String board = "App";
    String noteText ="descption"


    if (!Utils.isEmpty(noteText) && !Utils.isEmpty(board) &&
            !Utils.isEmpty(pinImageUrl)) {
        PDKClient.getInstance().createPin(noteText, board, pinImageUrl, "test", new PDKCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PDKResponse response) {

                Log.d("onSavePin-onSavePin--->"+getClass().getName() + "-->Save pin ", response.getData().toString());
                // responseView.setText(response.getData().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(PDKException exception) {

                Log.e("onSavePin-onFailure--->"+getClass().getName(), exception.getDetailMessage());
                //responseView.setText(exception.getDetailMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: check from site whether the board exists or not.

Comment: ya it exist, I need to create a pin to that board

Comment: confirm your board id i think you are using wrong board id.

Comment: Okay thanks, Will look board id

Comment: finally i found soltion

Comment: whats was the problem.

Comment: board = "App"; this is the problem, instead of board name("App") we need to give board id